# Variable as table name using Lisp/Postmodern/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, lisp, common-lisp

Can someone please give an example of how to write a row to a table using a variable as the table name in Lisp/Postmodern/S-SQL/PostgreSQL?

I am currently able to write to a table in PostgreSQL with `:insert-into` using the following function:

```
(defun save-event (table-name cost event-id)
  (defprepared insert-event
      (sql-compile `(:insert-into ,table-name :set 'cost ,cost
                                                   'event-id ,event-id)))
  (insert-event))
```

Using the input syntax:

```
(save-event 'table-name 33 1)
```

However, if I try and pass a string containing the desired table name to the function as follows:

```
(defparameter x "table-name")
(apply #'funcall `(save-event ',x 44 2))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Database error 42601: syntax error at or near "E'table-name'"
Query: INSERT INTO E'table-name' (cost, event_id) VALUES (44, 2)
   [Condition of type CL-POSTGRES-ERROR:SYNTAX-ERROR-OR-ACCESS-VIOLATION]
```

I have been stuck on this for quite a while, tried almost everything.  Got me stumped.

Answer (score 3):

If the code expects a symbol as table name you cannot pass a string, you must `intern` it.
Something like the following should work...

```
(defparameter x "table-name")
(save-event (intern x) 44 2)
```

In common lisp a symbol is a symbol and a string is a string. To get a string from a symbol you need to call `(symbol-name x)` to get a symbol from a string you need to call `(intern x)`.

Quasiquoting (back quoting) is not going to do this transformation. In other words:

```
(let ((test "foo"))
  `(this is a ,test))
--> (THIS IS A "foo")`
```

Depending on how the symbol is going to be used by that library may be even an "uninterned" symbol can be used instead of a regular interned symbol.

Those symbols can be created with `(make-symbol x)` but if this is acceptable or not depends on how the symbol is being used in the code; note also that while `(intern x)` will always return the same symbol if you call it multiple times with the same string this is not true for `(make-symbol x)` that instead will return a different fresh uninterned symbol each time is called.

```
(make-symbol "X")
--> #:X

(symbol-name (make-symbol "X"))
--> "X"

(eq (make-symbol "X") (make-symbol "X"))
--> NIL

(eq (intern "X") (intern "X"))
--> T
```

Comment: You can actually make uninterned symbols using MAKE-SYMBOL, so it's not necessary to "pollute" the name space by interning variables, unless you specifically need an interned symbol. If it's used only for its name, uninterned symbols should be OK.

Comment: @Vatine: Thanks, I added a small discussion about uninterned symbols to the answer